# Callback Mutation Inside Message Event

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, websocket, callback, mutation

So I ran into some Javascript weirdness if i write a function like this my passed callback works fine

```
messageHandler(callback) {
    this.ws.onmessage = (data) => {
        callback(data.data);
    };
}
```

If you write like this

```
messageHandler(callback) {
    this.ws.on('message', (data) => {
        callback(data);
    });
}
```

It mutates the callback into a message event I can't seem to figure out why but I'd like to understand this behavior if anyone can explain.  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why are you using `data` in one and `data.data` in the other?

Comment: The first example passes the message event.  The second passes just the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question omits crucial information but based on the code examples, I think you're using https://github.com/websockets/ws implementation, correct?

If so, then `.ws.on('message', ...` refers to [Event Emitter listener](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener). The params passed to your handler is the message or stream or whatever data object the emitter emits.

`.ws.onmessage` refers to the browser's [Websocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Websockets_API) - so the parameter passed there is a [MessageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent). As you can see from the spec, `data` is a property on `MessageEvent` class which explains why you have to refer with 1 level of indirection as `data.data`.

Perhaps it'd be less confusing if you call your parameter `event` instead of data in the first example:

```
this.ws.onmessage = (event) => {
    callback(event.data);
};
```

You can also view this as server side events vs. client side events - your first example is a client side event whereas the second example is a server side event. Client side events conform to [Websockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Websockets_API) whereas server side events, in NodeJS world, typically use event emitters.

Comment: I apologize I could have been more clear I just threw in the tags what I was doing.  I have to retest but I think my confusion was caused by my break points causing my callback to appear to be an emitter while still working properly once then crashing.

Comment: Ah I see. See that sounds like a wholly different question - "why does my callback appear to be en event emitter when debugging" or something like that. That would also tell that you're not new to these concepts, which would have saved me typing my current answer! :) Anyway, I'm just guessing here but sometimes stale/wrong source maps or debug symbols can cause that sort of confusion.

Comment: So I've gone ahead and took a second look and i'm still quite confused...  The first time it hits the breakpoint it passes the correct callback...  Maybe this image can help.  

https://imgur.com/a/azIGz3X

Comment: Like I said, you need to improve your question by providing more details What library are you using, what does rest of the source code look like and maybe a sample repo. Unfortunately, that image provides no *more* details than what you already said in your previous comment.

Comment: I am using the **ws** npm library.

-- So here is my callback --
`
launchContainer(message) {

        if (Helpers.parseMessage(message).type === "connect") {
            this._connection = Helpers.parseMessage(message).ID;
            this.state(4);
        }

    }
`
 -- passed through as an instance of a class helper --

`socket.messageHandler(helper.launchContainer.bind(helper));`

Comment: Okay, I think this is a bug but your answer was indeed helpful.